# why the small number string is greater than big number string in javascript

Tags: javascript

In some cases,the small number string is greater than big number string.

such as '2' is greater than '1000';

but '1' isn't greater than '1000';

and '2' isn't greater than '300'

I know that I am trying to comparing string,not a real number type,and it should be compare as lexical comparition.

I wanna ask what's the calculation principle of when these tow number string are comparing.

Comment: The strings are iterated over character-by-character. The first index for which the character is different in both strings determines whether the whole thing evaluates to true or false.

Comment: you're comparing strings ... and that is the lexical comparison result you'd expect

Comment: substitute A for 0, B for 1, C for 2 and D for 3 ... now is it more obvious?

Comment: @Bravo 2 is > 1, 1 is not > 1, 2 is not greater than 3. String comparison of a number in JS is treated like how @certainperformance above mentioned. Try converting the string to an integer before comparing using `parseInt()`

Comment: @SpencerMay - what are you going on about? the OP is dealing with STRINGS, he says so in the question - he just doesn't understand that, "2" > "1000" ... so I suggested looking at it like "C" > "BAAA"